# Do people use "rodar" for bike-riding outside of Mexico City? Did people use it thirty years ago?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, diferencias-regionales, méxico

In school I learned to translate *to ride a bike* as *montar en bicicleta*. SpanishDict.com confirms this translation and offers *andar en bicicleta* as well.

In Mexico City, though, I have exclusively heard *rodar en bicicleta*. However, while the verb *rodar* makes sense, meaning to *roll* or *turn*, I have not seen a direct reference to bike riding in the two Spanish to English dictionaries that I have checked.

My question is not whether *rodar en bicicleta* is a legitimate way to speak of riding a bike. I understand that there are many more ways to express an idea that what a class will teach. I also appreciate *rodar* because it makes sense even without adding *en bicicleta*, whereas (in my understanding) *montar* and *andar* do not.

**My question, instead, is whether this is a new or regional phrasing?** Do people use *rodar* for bike-riding outside of Mexico City? Did people use it thirty years ago?

Comment: I guess so, since I hadn't heard about this in Spain. However, the [diccionario de americanismos](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=xuefqWMQsx0AJMZ8Vfb) does not mention it, neither [RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WarJHV2). What I do use in Spain is _rodar_ in a sense of doing some sport, like running or cycling, when it consists in some aerobic exercise training: _esta tarde rodaré una horita por la montaña_.

Comment: I wouldn't have trouble understanding *rodar* if used with the word *bicicleta*, but I don't feel it's too common elsewhere.  As to it being legitimate, of course it is!  Regionalisms aren't incorrect just because they're not used elsewhere.  The interesting question to me would be how cognizant those from D.F. are and if they would register shift to use *andar/ir/montar* when speaking to non-Mexicans (or people from outside the capital), or if they'd make sure to use *bicicleta* always.

Comment: Also, Google NGrams doesn't show any instances, so between that and the diccionario de americanismos, I'd say it's probably relatively new.

Comment: Are you sure they weren't really saying *ondar*? That's what I was told to use in Mexico: *ondar en bicicleta* ...

Comment: @Robusto It's actually been on government signage. Wish I'd taken a photo.

Comment: Despite the fact that I'm not from Mexico city, I know a lot of people from there and and neither *rodar* nor *ondar* sound familiar to me for that context. I actually believe you heard the word *andar*. - ¿En qué *andas*? - *Ando* en bicicleta/taxi/metro/autobús.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a rare case in which Diccionario de americanismos does not mention any Mexican-specific definition:

> [**rodar**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=xuefqWMQsx0AJMZ8Vfb).
>   I.  1.  intr. Mx. Caer un caballo hacia delante.
>   II. 1.  tr. Ch. Desgastar algo o alguien un tornillo, tuerca o una pieza similar.
>   III.    1.  tr. CR. Ganar la voluntad de alguien con halagos para conseguir de él algo y, generalmente, para engañarlo. pop.
>   □
>   a. ǁ    ~ a patadas. loc. verb. Mx. Derribar algo o a alguien a puntapiés. pop + cult → espon.
>   b. ǁ    ~ tierras. loc. verb. Mx. Viajar, visitar otros lugares distintos al propio. pop + cult → espon.
>   c. ǁ    ~lo ponchado. loc. verb. Cu. Estar alguien muy deteriorado físicamente para su edad.

Neither does the DRAE, where we can find an entry that can refer to this:

> [**rodar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WarJHV2)
>   Del lat. rotāre 'mover circularmente', 'caer dando vueltas', der. de rota 'rueda'.
>   Conjug. c. contar.
>   1. tr. Hacer que un automóvil marche sin rebasar las velocidades prescritas por el fabricante para el rodaje.
>   2. tr. Registrar imágenes en una película cinematográfica. Rodó el incidente.
>   3. tr. Actuar en una película o dirigirla. Rodará su próxima película en París.
>   4. tr. Pasar o proyectar la película a mano por medio de un proyector.
>   5. tr. C. Rica. engatusar.
>   6. intr. Dicho de un cuerpo: Dar vueltas alrededor de un eje, sin mudar de lugar, como la piedra de un molino, o mudando, como la bola que corre por el suelo.
>   **7. intr. Moverse por medio de ruedas. *El automóvil rodó lentamente*.**
>   8. intr. Caer dando vueltas por una pendiente.
>   9. intr. Dicho de una cosa: No tener colocación fija.
>   10. intr. Ir de un lado para otro sin fijarse o establecerse en sitio determinado.
>   11. intr. Dicho del dinero: Abundar o correr. En aquella casa rueda el dinero.
>   12. intr. Andar inútilmente en pretensiones.
>   13. intr. coloq. Dicho de una persona: Estar pronta y dispuesta para servir a otra y hacer cuanto mande o pida, por difícil que sea. Estaba dispuesto a rodar POR aquel amigo.

Doing some research I found out that in Argentina they say [*andar en bicicleta*](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=ride), but nothing about some Mexican-specific term.

Googling a little bit I found many Mexican websites that refer to this. However, I also notices a little amount from Colombia:

- [‘La Escuela de la Bicicleta’: nuevo programa para **rodar** en Bogotá](http://hsbnoticias.com/noticias/bogota/la-escuela-de-la-bicicleta-nuevo-programa-para-rodar-en-bogo-219664)
- [**Rodar** cerca de Bogotá, destinos donde la “bici” es vida](http://www.elespectador.com/vivir/buen-viaje-vip/rodar-cerca-de-bogota-destinos-donde-bici-vida-articulo-561428)
- [Siete sucreños irán al Valle a **rodar** en bicicleta](http://www.eluniversal.com.co/deportes/siete-sucrenos-iran-al-valle-rodar-en-bicicleta-219135)

And also one from a Spanish newspaper (which may be explained by a journalist being from Mexico or Colombia):

- [Dani Alves aprovecha el día libre para **rodar** en bici](http://www.mundodeportivo.com/futbol/fc-barcelona/20160426/401376487772/dani-alves-aprovecha-el-dia-libre-para-rodar-en-bici.html)

This being said, my experience in Spain with the word *rodar* is to be used in a context of a group of people training for competitions. With this verb you can refer to running as well. Then, in these groups of people it is typical to say:

> Esta mañana he rodado una hora por la montaña.

Expressing some aerobic exercise training.

To sum up: it seems that Mexico is not the only place to use *rodar* in this context, having Colombia as a place in which this is used as well.

Regarding how long has this expression been used for, I cannot tell: Ngram does not show references for *rodar bicicleta*, while looking for *rodar* alone has too much noise to distinguish this subset.

Comment: Thanks for the research! Side note: I am struggling to interpret that first definition. I read it as for a horse to fall forward... but that doesn't really make sense? Am I reading it wrong or am I just not experienced enough with horses?

Comment: @Unrelated yes, you are understanding it well, so it is... _unrelated_ to the bikes. I added that definition from _Diccionario de americanismos_ to show that they do not have anything related to this topic.

Comment: No I totally understand that. I just don't get what it means related to horses.

Comment: @Unrelated you are right, _Caer un caballo hacia delante_ doesn't have much sense. I went through the entry [_caer_](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=caer) in the Diccionario de americanismos and I did not find any specific meaning of this, so it is just "falling down", because "falling forward" is quite hard to imagine.

Comment: phew feeling slightly less incompetent